# Scrollable Menu Tracking Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hell of a time trying to understand and then implement a working scrolling method.

**Goal:**
Create a big picture viewer/gallery. Users click on arrow keys or on thumbnails in a toggled menu to navigate through images. The gallery and menu should keep track of which thumbnail the users are viewing.

**Situation:**
I have a position:absolute #menu that slides to become visible when your mouse hovers over the right edge of the window. This #menu has a child #galleryMenu whose overflow:scroll. The result is scrollable menu that is navigated using the scroll wheel.

**Problem:**
Everytime the mouse hovers off the #menu, you lose your place. I don't know how to get the #menu to stay where the user left off.

Sample Website Link: http://bahaha.ga/?view=0

I've also tried a few plugins, but they cancel #galleryMenu's overflow:scroll and it ruins the overall #menu.

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is a simpler/cleaned up code to help communicate my goal/problem.

**HTML**

```
<div id="resolution">
    <div id="main">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="galleryMenu">
            <ul id="galleryThumbnail">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#resolution{
    position: absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#main{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#menu{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 0;
    width: 10px;
}

#galleryMenu{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 350px;
    right: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#galleryThumbnail{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#galleryThumbnail li{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
//Show and Hide Gallery Menu
$("#menu").hover(function(){
    $("#galleryMenu").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);} , function(){
    $("#galleryMenu").hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);}
);

//Set Window Height as Menu Heights
$("#menu").height($(window).height());
$("#galleryMenu").height($(window).height());

// Scroll to Current Thumbnail on Menu
$("#galleryMenu").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()}, 
    1400,
    "easeOutQuint"
);
```

Comment: Sorry, it should be working now ~ thanks!

Comment: what exactly u want? u want to display side bar when over the main image?

Comment: As you iterate through the gallery, each image that shows on #main has a corresponding thumbnail image under #menu but the moment you hover off of #menu and then back on - your scroll location is no longer saved. It starts from the beginning again. How do I get the scroll location to continue staying where it last left off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround. Using Jquery's slideUp() and slideDown() kept resetting the location of the #menu (instantly as soon as your mouse hovered off #menu).

Instead of using slideUp() and slideDown(), I ended up using .animate() to move #menu off the screen to the right. This made keeping track of the scroll position on #menu easier as user's hovered away temporarily.

Khaleel, thanks for the code, but it did not work for me. However, I managed to get a working code up:

```
//Menu : Scroll to Thumbnail
$("#galleryMenu").animate(
   {scrollTop: $("li:nth-child(<?php echo $currentImage ?>)").offset().top-()},
    500
);
```

Using the the UL's LI elements and a little bit of PHP, I was able to grab the nth-child of the li element that contained the thumbnail of the currently viewed image in order to center it onto #menu.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

you need this .

```
var tempScrollTop=0;
$(document).on( 'scroll', '#galleryMenu', function(){
    tempScrollTop = $(#galleryMenu).scrollTop();
});
$(document).on( 'hover', '#galleryMenu', function(){
   $(#galleryMenu).scrollTop(tempScrollTop);
});
```

Hope it helps